# rmagic rotation and background color is black

Tags: rotation, background-color, rmagick

```
img1 = Magick::Image.read("public/123.png").first
img1.background_color = "none"

img1.rotate!(30)
img1.write('test.png')
```

background color is black, how transparent

Anyone,help?

Answer (score 1):

```
img1 = Magick::Image.read("public/123.png").first
img1.background_color = "transparent"

img1.rotate!(30)
img1.write('test.png')
```